# 3次元データに対する tf.pad

Tags: tensorflow

ミラーパッディングを使いたいのですが、対象となるデータが３次元`[None,256,256]`の時，
`tf.pad`におけるpaddingsはどのように設計してやればいいですか？ご教授ください。

```py
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 256, 256])
paddings = tf.constant([[2, 2,], [2, 2]])
X_ = tf.pad(X, paddings, "REFLECT")
```

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MirrorPad_5' (op: 'MirrorPad') with input shapes: [?,256,256], [2,2].
```

追記：今、Xを`[None,256,256]`から`[None,260,260]`へと変形したいです。

Comment: すいません以下で解決しました。ありがとうございました。
X = tf.pad(X, [[0, 0], [2,2], [2,2]], "REFLECT")

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは、自己回答が可能です :)